# Inclusion exclusion principle: Counting ways to do bridge hands

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Need some help with some combinatorics problem! We are supposed to use the Inclusion-Exclusion principle to solve: "how many bridge hands contain exactly 3 clubs, or exactly 5 diamonds or exactly 3 aces?"
I know you do something like: 
|3 clubs|+|3aces|+|5dimonds| - |3clubs AND 3 aces| - |3clubs AND 5 diamonds| -...... +|all 3 intersected| 
But I'm really struggling with find the cases where the aces may or may not be a club/diamond.

Comment: Split the three aces into four events: (Ace Club, Ace Diamond, Ace Spade), (Ace Club, Ace Diamond, Ace Heart), (Ace Club, Ace Heart, Ace Spade), (Ace Heart, Ace Diamond, Ace Spade).

Comment: I would start by explaining to the audience how many cards(?) are in a Bridge hand, how many clubs in a deck, how many diamonds in a deck, how many aces in a deck, and how many other types in a deck. We're not professional Bridge players.

Answer (score 4):

$\begin{align}
\text{exactly }3\ \clubsuit
&=\underset{\clubsuit}{\binom{13}{3}}\binom{39}{10}=181\,823\,183\,256\\[6pt]
\text{exactly }5\ \diamondsuit
&=\underset{\diamondsuit}{\binom{13}{5}}\binom{39}{8}
=79\,181\,063\,676\\[6pt]
\text{exactly }3\ \text{A}
&=\underset{\text{A}}{\binom{4}{3}}\binom{48}{10}
=26\,162\,863\,584
\end{align}$

---

$\begin{align}
\text{exactly }3\ \clubsuit\text{ and }5\ \diamondsuit
&=\underset{\clubsuit}{\binom{13}{3}}\underset{\diamondsuit}{\binom{13}{5}}\binom{26}{5}
=24\,212\,433\,960\\[6pt]
\text{exactly }3\ \clubsuit\text{ and }3\ \text{A}
&=\overbrace{\underset{\clubsuit}{\binom{12}{2}}\underset{\text{A}}{\binom{3}{2}}\binom{36}{8}}^{\text{with A$\clubsuit$}}
+\overbrace{\underset{\clubsuit}{\binom{12}{3}}\underset{\text{A}}{\binom{3}{3}}\binom{36}{7}}^{\text{without A$\clubsuit$}}
=7\,828\,036\,920\\[6pt]
\text{exactly }5\ \diamondsuit\text{ and }3\ \text{A}
&=\overbrace{\underset{\diamondsuit}{\binom{12}{4}}\underset{\text{A}}{\binom{3}{2}}\binom{36}{6}}^{\text{with A$\diamondsuit$}}
+\overbrace{\underset{\diamondsuit}{\binom{12}{5}}\underset{\text{A}}{\binom{3}{3}}\binom{36}{5}}^{\text{without A$\diamondsuit$}}
=3\,191\,048\,784
\end{align}$

---

$\begin{align}
\text{exactly }3\ \clubsuit\text{ and }5\ \diamondsuit\text{ and }3\ \text{A}
&=\overbrace{\underset{\clubsuit}{\binom{12}{2}}\underset{\diamondsuit}{\binom{12}{4}}\underset{\text{A}}{\binom{2}{1}}\binom{24}{4}}^{\text{with A}\clubsuit\text{ and A}\diamondsuit}
+\overbrace{\underset{\clubsuit}{\binom{12}{2}}\underset{\diamondsuit}{\binom{12}{5}}\underset{\text{A}}{\binom{2}{2}}\binom{24}{3}}^{\text{with A}\clubsuit\text{ without A}\diamondsuit}\\[6pt]
&+\overbrace{\underset{\clubsuit}{\binom{12}{3}}\underset{\diamondsuit}{\binom{12}{4}}\underset{\text{A}}{\binom{2}{2}}\binom{24}{3}}^{\text{without A}\clubsuit\text{ with A}\diamondsuit}
+\overbrace{\underset{\clubsuit}{\binom{12}{3}}\underset{\diamondsuit}{\binom{12}{5}}\underset{\text{A}}{\color{#C00000}{\binom{2}{3}}}\binom{24}{2}}^{\text{without A}\clubsuit\text{ or A}\diamondsuit}\\[9pt]
&=1\,020\,514\,968
\end{align}$

---

Inclusion-Exclusion says we have
$$
\begin{align}
&(181\,823\,183\,256+79\,181\,063\,676+26\,162\,863\,584)\\
&-(24\,212\,433\,960+7\,828\,036\,920+3\,191\,048\,784)\\
&+1\,020\,514\,968\\
&=252\,956\,105\,820
\end{align}
$$
bridge hands with exactly $3\ \clubsuit$ or exactly $5\ \diamondsuit$ or exactly $3\ \text{A}$.

Since there are $\binom{52}{13}=635\,013\,559\,600$ bridge hands, the probability of the specified hands is approximately $39.834756596275\%$.

Comment: +1, for the formatting and the inclusion of the suit symbols.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let’s assemble the pieces. The first four are straightforward, and I’ll just state them without explanation, but feel free to ask about them if necessary.

- There are $\binom{13}3\binom{39}{10}$ hands with exactly $3$ clubs.
- There are $\binom{13}5\binom{39}8$ hands with exactly $5$ diamonds.
- There are $\binom43\binom{48}{10}$ hands with exactly $3$ aces.
- There are $\binom{13}3\binom{13}5\binom{26}5$ hands with exactly $3$ clubs and exactly $5$ diamonds.

Now we’ll tackle counting the hands with exactly $3$ clubs and exactly $3$ aces. There are two possibilities.

- If the hand includes the ace of clubs, it must contain exactly $2$ other clubs and exactly $2$ other aces. There are $\binom{12}2\binom32$ ways to pick these $4$ cards and $\binom{36}8$ ways to pick the remaining $8$ cards from the $36$ cards that are neither club nor ace, so there are $\binom{12}2\binom32\binom{36}8$ hands in this case.
- If the hand does not include the ace of clubs, it must have all $3$ of the other aces. That leaves $10$ cards to be chosen, exactly $3$ of which must be clubs. All $13$ clubs are still available, so there are $\binom{12}3$ ways to choose the $3$ clubs; that leaves $36$ cards that are neither ace nor club, and we must choose $7$ of them, so there are $\binom{12}3\binom{36}7$ hands in this case.

Thus, there are $\binom{12}2\binom32\binom{36}8+\binom{12}3\binom{36}7$ hands with exactly $3$ clubs and exactly $3$ aces.

You can use essentially the same analysis to find the number of hands with exactly $3$ aces and exactly $5$ diamonds.

The final piece needed is the number of hands with exactly $3$ aces, exactly $3$ clubs, and exactly $5$ diamonds. The analysis here works the same way, except that you should break it into four cases:

- the hand includes both the ace of clubs and the ace of diamonds;
- the hand includes the ace of clubs but not the ace of diamonds;
- the hand includes the ace of diamonds but not the ace of clubs;
- the hand includes neither the ace of clubs nor the ace of diamonds.

Comment: In the computation of the $3$ clubs and $3$ aces, there are two cases: with and without the ace of clubs. The case with the ace of clubs seems correct. However, I believe the case without the ace of clubs should count $\binom{12}{3}$ ways of choosing $3$ clubs from the clubs *minus the ace*. Otherwise, I think our counts agree. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn: Yep; hit the wrong key and didn't notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to calculate directly. Let us define the following events:

$A_S:$ hand contains Ace Club, Ace Diamond, Ace Hearts

$A_C:$ hand contains Ace Spade, Ace Diamond, Ace Hearts

$A_D:$ hand contains Ace Spade, Ace Club, Ace Hearts

$A_H:$ hand contains Ace Spade, Ace Diamond, Ace Club

For $A_S$, the number of hands that also satisfy the other conditions is 
$$\binom{12}{2}\binom{12}{4}\binom{24}{4}$$
since we need to choose 2 non ace clubs, 4 non ace diamonds and with Ace of heart being present adn Ace of spade excluded, we have 24 cards to choose 4 remaining cards.
Similarly for $A_C$, we have 
$$\binom{12}{3}\binom{12}{4}\binom{24}{3}$$
choices. For $A_D$, the choices are
$$\binom{12}{2}\binom{12}{5}\binom{24}{3}$$
and for $A_H$, we have
$$\binom{12}{2}\binom{12}{4}\binom{24}{4}$$
choices. We add the above to get the total.